# AVAudioPlayer not playing the MP3

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I need to reproduce an MP3 file and I'm using this code:

```
import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

@IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

   //Making the phone vibrate
   AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

   //Playing a sound
   let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audio_file_name", withExtension: "mp3")!
   do {
      self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
      self.player?.delegate = self
      self.player?.prepareToPlay()
      self.player?.play()
   } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
}
```

I'm not getting any error, but no sound is reproduced. I've also enabled Inter-App audio in the App Capabilities, added the MP3 file in "Copy Bundle Resources" and I'm testing on a real device. 
Any suggestion? I've tried all the other solutions provided in other questions of this type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved.

Everything was not working just because I was reproducing this code in a background queue.
Moving it to the main queue just solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this piece of code worked for me fine

```
func playAudio(){
     let audioUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: value, relativeTo: someBasePath)
            do{
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioUrl, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
}
```

and you have to define `audioPlayer` as a class member or it goes out of scope otherwise and it won't work.

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

thats it

Comment: I just do not understand the -1? for a working piece of code? which answers the question.